# Is it a [bug], is it a feature? Do we really need a [bug] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking at the main site, we currently have [bug](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag. (53 questions are tagged with it.)

It has no usage guidelines.

Is it noise? Do we need to keep it, if so, what should be its usage guideline/how would be use it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we need it, and it should be removed:

- Considering that a lot of users come here to ask about bugs they have with their project, that would mean that a large proportion of the new questions would need to be tagged as such, while the others would need to be properly categorized as [architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture), [art](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art), etc. I think this does not make much sense.
- I don't think someone could be considered expert in 'bugs' (but they could be very good at [debugging](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging)).
- It seems to be a meta tag, I don't think a question could be only tagged with `bug`.

Comment: Would we merge "bug" into "debugging"?

Comment: I don't think we should blindly do that, no. Debugging is about the process of finding bugs, and I doubt most [tag:bug] questions are actually about that process, but are rather about "I have this bug that I need help with".

Comment: In that case, I have been misusing the debugging tag! Thanks for the clarification, I'll fix my use of it going forward.

Comment: I agree. The alternative I see still has the problem of being meta-tags:
[x] + [debugging] means that the thing I made in [x] isn't working as expected. For instance, there's an error in my Java code somewhere.
[x] + [bug] means that I'm trying to use [x] to make something and it isn't working. For instance, Netbeans doesn't give me the option to run my code.

Comment: Revisiting this as I just ran into [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/188013/33287) using the [tag:bug] tag. Does the relatively low voting suggest that the tag stays as is?

Comment: @Pikalek I think the "low voting" here reflects lack of interest and/or the question was not asked during a "peak of activity", not the "disagree" because there are no downvotes. The tag is on my list of those to be removed.