# Do we need the [crash] tag?

Tags: discussion

Just ran into the [crash](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crash) tag [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/176601/33287). There's only 4 questions using it right now.

Related reading:

- [Do we really need a [bug] tag?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2798/33287)
- [Do we need the [error-management] tag?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2805/33287)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn’t seem very useful to me.